# Querystring of a javascript object

Tags: node.js, api, http

I need to make a HTTP GET request but i have some trouble with making a querystring of a javascript object. This is my object.

```
var params = {
  from: {
      zip: '42100',
      country: 'IT'
  },
  to: {
      zip: '20019',
      country: 'IT'
  },
  packages: [ { "width": 50, "height": 40, "length": 40, "weight": 2 } ]
};
```

I manually made my querystring and this is the result

```
from[zip]=42100&from[country]=IT&to[zip]=20019&to[country]=IT&packages[0]=[width]=50&[height]=40&[length]=40&[weight]=2
```

The problem is that Google says "Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request."

This is my NodeJS script.

```
var request = require('request');

var params = {
    from: {
        zip: '42100',
        country: 'IT'
    },
    to: {
        zip: '20019',
        country: 'IT'
    },
    packages: [ { "width": 50, "height": 40, "length": 40, "weight": 2 } ]
};

function packagesToQueryString(packages) {
    let stringa = "";
    for (const onePackage of packages) {
        stringa += '[width]='+ onePackage.width + '&[height]='+ onePackage.height +'&[length]='+ onePackage.length +'&[weight]='+ onePackage.weight +'';
    }
    return 'packages[' + (packages.length - 1) + ']=' + stringa;
}


function paramsToQueryString(obj) {
    return 'from[zip]=' + obj.from.zip +'&from[country]=' + obj.from.country + '&to[zip]=' + obj.to.zip + '&to[country]=' + obj.to.country+ '&';
}

const formData = paramsToQueryString(params) + packagesToQueryString(params.packages);
console.log(formData);

request({
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'fcd3dda8...2577',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: formData,
    uri: 'https://api.packlink.com/v1/services',
    method: 'GET'
}, function (err, res, body) {
    console.log(body);
});
```

[Google error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nf3Qe.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "Google says..."? Is it a warning from Chrome? Can you provide some screenshot?

Comment: google error added

Comment: I can see what's going wrong now. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 reasons that causes the "malformed or illegal request" error:

1. In your HTTP request, the `Content-Type` is defined as `application/json`. However, the value of `body` is `formData` (`from[zip]=42100&from[country]=...`), which is NOT json.
2. Even for the `formData`, your assemble logic is incorrect. For `params` object, its corresponding query string is: `from%5Bzip%5D=42100&from%5Bcountry%5D=IT&to%5Bzip%5D=20019&to%5Bcountry%5D=IT&packages%5B0%5D%5Bwidth%5D=50&packages%5B0%5D%5Bheight%5D=40&packages%5B0%5D%5Blength%5D=40&packages%5B0%5D%5Bweight%5D=2`

In order to successfully send that HTTP GET request, you need to use the `qs` option of `request` module. The code would look like below:

```
var request = require('request');

var params = {
  from: {
    zip: '42100',
    country: 'IT'
  },
  to: {
    zip: '20019',
    country: 'IT'
  },
  packages: [ { "width": 50, "height": 40, "length": 40, "weight": 2 } ]
};

request({
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'fcd3dda8...2577'
  },
  qs: params,
  uri: 'https://api.packlink.com/v1/services',
  method: 'GET'
}, function (err, res, body) {
  console.log(body);
});
```